# Add listener to ListView of contacts?

Tags: android

I need some help to add an onItemClickListener to a ListView of contacts. I want to capture some information from the selected contacts like name, phonenumbers and other info and pass it to another activity.

I'm not sure how to add a onListItemListener to my code below and how to capture info from the selected contact? I also wonder how to pass more than one value with an Intent? I use this for one value:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity_1.this, Activity_2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("imageId", imagePath);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And here are my code in the activity with the ListView. I got some help here yesterday and I wonder if the  while (cursor.moveToNext()){} part of the code is important for the ListView since it works without it?

Preciate some help! Thanks!

```
public class Activity_3 extends Activity {

ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactList);

    String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, 
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, 
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};

    // Get a cursor with all people
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,null,null, null);
    //Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,null,null, null);


    String[] fromColumn = {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    int[] toView = {R.id.contactItem };

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
         String Name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
         String Number=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    }
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_3, cursor, fromColumn, toView );

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view , int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        do your operations here...

            }
        });


use this onitemclicklistener to listen to your listview clicks .
```

Comment: That's what I have been trying to do several times, but I just get red lines below setOnItemVlickListener with this error message: The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

Comment: import AdapterView for onItemCLickListener